# Is there a way to make an animation finish upon aborting?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm coding a media player, and I have used JavaScript and CSS to make the song meta information scroll in a marquee-style effect, but only when the track is playing. I used JS to add/remove the animation class when you press the play/pause button. I was wondering if there was any way to let the animation play to completion before stopping, if the animation class is removed in the middle of it.

```js
var MetaScroll = document.getElementById("MetaScroll");
var PlayButton = document.getElementById("PlayButton");

function playPause() {
  MetaScroll.classList.toggle('scrolling');
  PlayButton.classList.toggle('fa-play');
  PlayButton.classList.toggle('fa-pause');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.albumArt {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #212121;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.metaContainer {
  height: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.meta {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.meta p {
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}

.scrolling {
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: b-text-scroll 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes b-text-scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.pIcons {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1706aa300d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="albumArt">
    <div class="metaContainer">
      <div id="MetaScroll" class="meta">
        <p>&nbsp; The Absense of a Title - A Deadly Lack of Artist</p>
        <p>&nbsp; The Absense of a Title - A Deadly Lack of Artist</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="pIcons" onclick="playPause()">
    <i id="PlayButton" class="fa-solid fa-play"></i>
  </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a bit more logic than you're using now, but instead of removing the class when you pause, you could add an [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event) event listener at that moment, and remove the class when that event triggers.

```js
var MetaScroll = document.getElementById("MetaScroll");
var PlayButton = document.getElementById("PlayButton");

function playPause() {
    // You need a way to track whether this is a play or pause action
    // Assume here that the variable pause is true when the click represents pausing
    if (pause) {
        // Let the animation continue, but add an event lister for when it ends
        MetaScroll.addEventListener('animationend', endAnimationAfterCompletion);
    } else {
        MetaScroll.classList.add('scrolling');
        // Remove the event listener so it doesn't fire if a user pause and then unpaused before the 'animationend' event had time to fire
        MetaScroll.removeEventListener('animationend', endAnimationAfterCompletion);
    }
    PlayButton.classList.toggle('fa-play');
    PlayButton.classList.toggle('fa-pause');
}

function endAnimationAfterCompletion() {
    MetaScroll.classList.remove('scrolling');
}
```